# Internet Explorer Shows CSS issue with outline-offset

Tags: css, internet-explorer

`outline-offset:-5px.` It is Working Fine in Chrome and FF and only in
  IE showing issue.

How can i make possible outline-offset:-5px [Negative value] in IE. is there any alternate       solution without using border ?

Comment: See this post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112968/css-outline-offset-alternative-for-ie

Comment: Dear all this answer is Outline offset show issue in IE. Instead of Outline offset we can use      box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px red;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE does not support `outline-offset`. And you should test it in opera too. becouse if i correctly remember Opera does not suppot negative values...