# CSS: increase the gap between the outline and border of div

Tags: html, css, border, space, outline

Am stack!... Is there a way to increase the gap between the `outline` *(overall line)* and the `border` *(`div`'s immediate line)* ?

For instance, I got:

[CODE]

```
    <div style="border:5px solid red; outline:3px solid green \\--->GAP ?; >
//Inside Div
```

```
|---------------`OutLine`--------------------



-------> *this GAP*



      |-------------------`border`--------------------

          |---------------`<div>`--------------------|
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`outline-offset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset) property — [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwPnL/)

Comment: It's worth noting that this property is not currently supported by IE.

Comment: Cool... thanks!... But it says not supported in IE. Any workaround for IE?

Comment: @UniversalGrasp,

True... here's the solution with pseudoelements (IE8+) - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13115325/2102296

Comment: Sure, answer accepted... though am forced to go through the **pain** of having a separate **CSS file** specially meant for `IE` [ _Thanks to IE Developpers_ ]