# CSS outline that includes margins

Tags: css

I am trying to highlight elements on mouseover similar to the Chrome Inspector / Firebug by adding `outline: 4px solid green` with CSS.
Using `outline` works fine since it does not take up any space in the box model. This way, the layout does not break and everything stays in place.

My approach works fine for elements with `width`, `height`, `padding` and `border`. However, `outline` does not include the `margin`.

I am looking for any easy solution, so that the `outline` wraps around the whole element including `margin`.
I have found `outline-offset` which offsets the outline by a custom amount of pixels, but is not supported in IE and is the same on all four sides.

If possible, I would like to avoid having to add 4 `<div />`s for the four sides to imitate the `outline`'s behaviour. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112968/css-outline-offset-alternative-for-ie

Comment: I would suggest using pseudo classes

Comment: Problem is, if you use css properties or pseudo classes you will likely overwrite existing styling

Comment: @Morpheus, suggest a pseudo class then...........

Comment: The answer is already provided @odedta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution could be to use an absolutely positionned pseudo element and apply a border to it on hover.

You can give the pseudo element top/bottom and left/right values that compensate the margins of the element :

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background:gold;
  z-index:1;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: -40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index:-1;
}
div:hover:after {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>content <a href="#">link</a></div>
```

Comment: Very nice! Why did you add the `z-index: -1`? It seems to create problems when hovering in from the left and the right...

Comment: @Horen the negative `z-index` prevents the pseudo element to be over the element itself. If you have interactive elements in it (like a link) wouldn't be clickable behind the pseudo element. I also corrected the issue you are talking about bu adding a z-index to the div too.

Comment: @Horen I also added a link in the div. Try removing the z-index ad you will see what I am talking about.