# Dashed outline with outline-offset not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, internet-explorer

i have to add dashed outline on focus at a specific offset of 4px, this is working fine in all browsers except IE since it doesn't support outline-offset and i cannot add a wrapper element in the HTML as work around with padding because i am trying to make a generic fix across the application, and i cannot add a border: 4px solid transparent, because the elements have a border which is required, and Pseudo elements will not work because we have a pseudo class of focus and we cannot use box-shadow as it doesn't allow a dashed outline

[image]

this is what i want to achieve in IE.

Css which is working fine on chrome

```
.keyBoardUser input[type="radio"]:focus + div {
  //border: 4px solid transparent // cannot use this
  outline-offset: 4px;
  outline: 1px dashed black;
}
```

keyboard user is a class which is added on tabbing using JS.

Comment: outline-offset is not compatible with IE check here -- https://caniuse.com/#search=outline-offset

Comment: @SumitPatel yes that's is the question is all about, i need a work around for this case. if the outline is not dashed the work around is pretty simple but since it's dashed i am not able to come up with a solution

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112968/css-outline-offset-alternative-for-ie)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112968/css-outline-offset-alternative-for-ie), use CSS pseudo elements or nested div to set the border property, and use it as a alternative method.

Sample code as below:

```
<style> 
    .keyBoardUser {
        margin-left:20px;
        text-align: center;
        width:30px;
    }
    input[type="radio"]{
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
    }

    @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
        .keyBoardUser input[type="radio"]:focus + div { 
            outline-offset: 6px;
            outline: 2px dashed black;
        }
    }
        /*Microsft Edge browser*/
    @supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
        .keyBoardUser input[type="radio"]:focus + div { 
            outline-offset: 6px;
            outline: 2px dashed black;
        }
    }
        /*IE Browser*/
    @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
        .box {
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .keyBoardUser input[type="radio"]:focus + div:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: -6px;
            left: -6px;
            display: block;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            border: 2px dashed red;
        }

        .box input[type="radio"] {
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
    } 
</style>
```

Html code as below:

```
<div class="keyBoardUser ">
    <input id="Radio1" type="radio" />  
    <div class="box"><input id="Radio1" type="radio" checked="checked" /></div>
</div>
```

The output like this:

IE browser:

[image]

Chrome browser:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a pseudo element on the sibling element to style the dashed outline. I am calculating the width and height dynamically.

Use the below class. This works on IE as well!

```
.keyBoardUser input[type="radio"]:focus + div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  outline: 1px dashed #000;
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  height: calc(100% + 10px);
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
}
```