# React ref's focus behaviour is not consistent in chrome,firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was working with refs in react. I noticed that the `.focus()` method is not consistent in chrome and firefox.

[image]

In this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/a-guide-to-react-refs-2nd-example-vl9sj?file=/src/Ref.js

I have created a lot of input fields and there is ref in the first input field. When the user clicks the submit button i call the `.focus()` method on the input ref.

And as you can see in the picture below.

Left pic-> firefox

Right pix-> Chrome

As you see chrome adds certain space above it when it focus but firefox does not. This is the same behaviour show in IE.

Is there any way to have consistent behaviour in both of them. Or is there anything else I can do except for focus to get the focus behaviour?

**Edit in IE:**

```
.focus {
  outline: #015ecc solid 2px;
  outline-offset: -2px;  // You don't always need to provide offset. But in some scenarios you might need to provide outline offset as it's not default offset property.
      ::-ms-focus-inner {  //FF adds some inner border to the elements, this will remove it.
        border: 0;
      }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you'll get different behaviour in different browsers when you focus.

Chrome uses webkit-focus-ring
In Element section when you focus the element you can see something like this,

```
outline: webkit-focus-ring-color auto 2px;
```

In FF, this outline will be different.

So in order to have same consistent behaviour for focus in multiple browsers, you need to mention your outline behaviour.

In your css you have to do something like below,

```
    .focus {
    outline: #015ecc solid 2px;
    outline-offset: -2px;  // You don't always need to provide offset. But in some scenarios you might need to provide outline offset as it's not default offset property.
        ::-moz-focus-inner {  //FF adds some inner border to the elements, this will remove it.
          border: 0;
        }
      }
```

So by adding the above CSS, you will get consistent behaviour in all browsers on focus. There may be chances that depending upon your usecase you need to add this CSS with pseudo selectors such as ::after, ::before.

Adding screenshot from your sandbox link for more clarity,

[image]

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks it helps. I beleive this will work in IE too right?

Comment: For IE, not sure right now. But I guess it will work too because we're specifying that we need outline. If not, then please let me know happy to help :)

Comment: I think it is not taking the property

Comment: Yes it'll not work in IE. If you really need to support IE, please have a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112968/css-outline-offset-alternative-for-ie

This should be incorporated with my changes to fulfil your requirements.